# bash script: apache processlist for specific user where C = 0

Tags: apache, bash

I'm writing a bash script and need to retrieve the process list from apache for a specific user where the C value (processor utilization) is zero. I then want to kill just those processes. my script currently looks like this:

```
process_user=myuser
max_instances=10
poll_interval=60

while true; do 
  count=$(ps -u $process_user | wc -l)
  echo "count: $count"
  if [[ $count > $max_instances ]]; then
    killall "$process_user"
    echo "Found $count $process_user processes. Killed."
  fi
  sleep "$poll_interval"
done
```

The above works fine for identifying the processes for a specific user and killing them. But I don't know how to further limit by whether processor utilization is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
process_user=myuser
max_instances=10
pool_interval=60

while sleep $pool_interval;do 
  ps -o pid,c -u $process_user --no-headers \
  | awk '                                   \
    $2 > 0{top=top " " $1}                  \
    {count++}                               \
    END {                                   \
      if(count > '$max_instances'  && top){ \
        system("kill " top);                \
        print "killed: " top                \
      }                                     \
    }'
done
```

Some explanations:

1. `ps -o pid,c -u $user --no-headers` 
   Show **pid** and processor utilization (**c**) of processes owned by `$user`. Skip the header (`PID  C`)
2. `$2 > 0` - this `{}` block will be executed only for lines where the second field (processor utilization) is greated then 0.
3. `{ top = top ' ' $1 }` append **pid** (first field - `$1`) to variable `top` separating with space
4. `{count++}` count all the lines = user processes
5. `END {` this block will be executed after all the lines were processes